# StatusStrip - Add a button without the dropdown arrow to the right of it

Tags: c#, statusstrip

I know there is a ToolStripSplitButton...

[image: ToolStripSplitButtonWithDropDown]

... but is there any way to use that button object without the dropdown arrow to the right of it.  Ending up with JUST an image that's a button?

[image: ToolStripSplitButtonWithoutDropDown]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found it... Set the DropdownButtonWidth to 0...

Comment: I swear sometimes...  I stare at something for 10 mins and can not see it...  I look on the stack and can't find a quick and simple answer...  So I ask it and spend 10 mins asking it...  After I'm done I look back to the other monitor and it slaps me in the face... Then I go to answer my own question to help others out...  30 mins later I continue to code...  Gezz...

Comment: I couldn't find this property, but setting "ShowDropDownArrow" to false provided the same effect.

Comment: DropdownButtonWidth for [ToolStripSplitButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripsplitbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and ShowDropDownArrow for [toolStripDropDownButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

Use ToolStripDropDownButton wo dropdown items.

Set ToolStripDropDownButton.ShowDropDownArrow = false;

(I tried a method "Set the DropdownButtonWidth to 0", but to me continues to see several Pixels from black triangle)

Comment: Weird.  It works perfect for me.  I'm always working in c#v4  maybe that's something new in new framework?

Comment: I am working in 4.5.1 and I see the pixels too. But using a DropDownButton works great.